# SVG change animation duration on hover

Tags: reactjs, svg, svg-filters, svg-animate

I am trying to animate an SVG with a linear gradient and I am struggling a little bit with the duration of it.
So, the rational here is I have 2 different colours (gradient) and on hover of the parent component I start or stop animating.

```
<linearGradient id="prefix__d" x1="95.55%" x2="6.387%" y1="50%" y2="50%">
   <stop offset="0%" stopColor="#0975E0" >
      <animate id="a1" attributeName="stop-color" values="#0975E0; #114BD5" begin="0; a2.end" dur={animationSpeed} />
      <animate id="a2" attributeName="stop-color" values="#114BD5; #0975E0" begin="a1.end" dur={animationSpeed} />
   </stop>
   <stop offset="100%" stopColor="#114BD5" >
     <animate id="a3" attributeName="stop-color" values="#114BD5; #0975E0" begin="0; a4.end" dur={animationSpeed} />
       <animate id="a4" attributeName="stop-color" values="#0975E0; #114BD5" begin="a3.end" dur={animationSpeed} />
   </stop>
 </linearGradient>
```

The initial animation speed is 0, as I want to animate it only when the user has their mouse over my button.

```
const [hoverSpeed, setHoverSpeed] =  useState('0');
```

and I am changing the value here

```
<Element 
    id={id}
    href={href}
    target={target}
    onMouseEnter={() => setHoverSpeed('1s')}
    onMouseLeave={() => setHoverSpeed('0')}
    data-speed={hoverSpeed} // just for debugging
  >
```

The point is, it seems to not "re-render" the animate from its initial value. I tried doing the opposite, starting with '1s' and changing to 0 and it also didn't stop the animation.

How can I achieve something like ?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I tried another approach which didnt work. I might have implemented wrong.
I have a fixed value for the animation duration and I have a conditional render for the animate tag.

```
const [active, setActive] =  useState(false);

onMouseEnter={() => setActive(true)}
onMouseLeave={() => setActive(false)}

{active && (
   <>
      <animate id="a1" attributeName="stop-color" values="#0975E0; #114BD5" begin="0; a2.end" dur='1s' />
      <animate id="a2" attributeName="stop-color" values="#114BD5; #0975E0" begin="a1.end" dur='1s' />
   </>
)}
```

Comment: Why not have a fixed duration and simply trigger it on hover/mouseover?

Comment: how ? Tried a conditional render for the <animate>, but it triggers only once then it stops. @RobertLongson

Comment: I have update it @RobertLongson .